# Hibernate UserType and a defined length

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I have a hibernate Usertype something like this:

```
public class UUIDHibernateType implements UserType
{
    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = new int[] { Types.CHAR };

    public int[] sqlTypes ()
    {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The problem I have is, that hibernate generates a sql script with the types CHAR(1) which is not correct, I would actually need CHAR(36). How would I define the default length of a custom type?

For the moment I'm stuck with defining the sql-type like this:

```
<id name="id"
    type="org.openscada.ae.server.storage.jdbc.internal.UUIDHibernateType">
    <column name="ID" length="36" sql-type="CHAR(36)" not-null="true" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

It shouldn't be a problem in this case, but how would I do it if the need arises?

PS: If someone has a better idea how to handle UUIDs transparently and database agnostig, I'm grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the built-in UUID generator of Hibernate (see [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)). Hibernate should then figure out the correct mapping and size, etc. of the PK column.

Comment: this is not an option, I have to provide the id by myself, because it needs to be created before the object is saved (the actual saving happens asynchronously).

Comment: In that case, look at the source code of the UUID generator how it specifies the column size.

Comment: that is definitely an idea, I will have a look, but I guess I will find it somewhere in each dialect implementation, because uuids and guids are not natively available in any database.

Answer (score 0):

The code returned by UserType.sqlTypes is used in the Dialect to look up the registered type.  So if you have sqlTypes return a code that isn't already in use, you can subclass your Dialect and register that code as a char(36).  For example:

// in your custom type
public int[] sqlTypes() {
  return new int[] { 1337 };
}

// in your custom dialect
registerColumnType(1337, "char(36)")

I haven't tried it, but it's been reported to work on the Hibernate forums.

Comment: sounds good in principle, but I can't subclass the dialect, because the user (implementor) should be able to specify it's own dialect, without having to worry about the mapping at all. But I will have a look if it is possible to add this type within the session factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also map your UUID to a BigInteger (java.sql.Types.BIGINT) in your UserType if you don't care about how your UUID is represented in your database (in this case, it will be represented in base 10).