# How to set hibernate-mapping to allow for Strings longer than 255 characters?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So I'm trying to learn by creating a blog-engine.  I'm using Hibernate with MySQL.  Here is my hibernate-mapping for the "Post" class:

```
 <hibernate-mapping package="com.enw.blog">
   <class name="Post" table="POST">
     <id name="id" column="POST_ID">
       <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property name="title"/>
     <property name="text"/>
     <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="POST_DATE"/>
   </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Of course, a post could be long.  By default this sets up a table with the Strings represented as `VARCHAR(255)`.  How do I alter this?

I'd also appreciate a pointer to the right place in the docs, I can't seem to navigate them effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` should do the job!

```
<property name="title" length="1234"/>
```

See [Chapter 5. Basic O/R Mapping: Property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with either annotations

```
@Column(length=256)
```

or XML

```
<property name="name" type="java.lang.String"> 
    <column name="COLUMN" length="256"/> 
</property>
```

Another thing, you can also change the `sql-type` if you want to use a specific type.

**Sources :**

- [Hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=926492)

**Related topics :**

- [Hibernate UserType and a defined length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007013/hibernate-usertype-and-a-defined-length)