# How to persist a large JSON String in SQL Server using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, json, string, hibernate

I have a very large JSON String that i need to store in the data, by very large means more than 48000 characters, and i am using SQL server to store this data in field of `text` type, then i tried changing it to `nvarchar(max)` but still seems no difference.

The problem that is occurring my string gets truncated after 40000 characters when i insert in the DB. i am using hibernate to store the data in that particular column and mapping it as `java.lang.String`

following is my code that converts from object to jsonobject

```
public static JSONObject toJSONListWithKey(List<?> object, String key) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            for (Object object2 : object) {
                jsonArray.put(new JSONObject(gson.toJson(object2)));
        }

            if (null != key || !"".equals(key)) {
                jsonObject.put(key, jsonArray);
            } else {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
}
```

and the following is the way i store it in the db

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONUtils.toJSONListWithKey(reports,"reports");

ins.setReportJson(jsonObject.toString());

instanceDAO.update(ins);
```

Can anyone please suggest/guide me where might things be going wrong and what should i adopt if this approach is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to modify the `ins` mapping, so the `reportJson` column admits a larger string, maybe even change the type to `TEXT`. If you're using XML files for the mapping configuration, you can specify the column type like this:

```
<property name="reportJson" >
  <column name="reportJson" sql-type="TEXT"/>
</property>
```

You might find this other question helpful:

[how to set length of an column in hibernate with maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363969/how-to-set-length-of-an-column-in-hibernate-with-maximum-length)

Comment: can string not be mapped to TEXT datatype? currently it is like this: `<property name="reportJson" type="string">
   <column name="reportJson" />
</property>`

Comment: By default, strings are mapped as VARCHAR. If you don't specify a length for it, it might be a default one that doesn't suit your current needs. You can specify it with your current configuration as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584509/how-to-set-hibernate-mapping-to-allow-for-strings-longer-than-255-characters

Comment: What you need to change is the type of the SQL column, not the Java type. It's still a string, but on the database it will be mapped as TEXT.

Comment: i dont want to specify length of my column as it may vary actually it is not specified can be longer or shorter because it is generated on run-time, in this case should i specify the max length as for the TEXT datatype?

Comment: You don't need to specify any length if you map your field to a SQL TEXT type. According to this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/type/TextType.html, it'll map your field as a SQL CLOB, which are designed to be huge, like 2GB huge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object

Comment: ok thanks i have accepted your answer, i am still testing on it, will let you know if i find any update. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can easily map a JSON column type to a JPA entity using the [`Hibernate Types`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) open-source project.

Now, assuming you have the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    isbn VARCHAR(15),
    properties NVARCHAR(4000) CHECK(
        ISJSON(properties) = 1
    )
)
```

You can map the JSON `properties` columns in two ways:

- as a Java `String`
- as a POJO

### Mapping the JSON column as a String entity attribute

The most flexible way of mapping the JSON column is to use a `String` entity attribute that's handled by the [`JsonType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-server-json-hibernate/).

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDef(
    name = "json",
    typeClass = JsonType.class
)
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @NaturalId
    @Column(length = 15)
    private String isbn;
 
    @Type(type = "json")
    private String properties;
 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public Book setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
 
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
 
    public Book setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        return this;
    }
 
    public String getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
 
    public Book setProperties(String properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        return this;
    }
 
    public JsonNode getJsonNodeProperties() {
        return JacksonUtil.toJsonNode(properties);
    }
}
```

### Mapping the JSON column as a POJO entity attribute

You are not limited to using a String entity attribute. You can use a POJO as well, considering that the POJO properties match the JSON attributes:

[image: Entity using JSON]

This time, the properties entity attribute will be mapped like this:

```
@Type(type = "json")
private BookProperties properties;
```

Using a POJO instead of a String-based JSON attribute allows us to simplify the read and write operations on the application side.

Notice how nicely we can build a Book entity instance thanks to the Fluent-style API employed by both the entity and the POJO class:

```
entityManager.persist(
    new Book()
        .setId(1L)
        .setIsbn("978-9730228236")
        .setProperties(
            new BookProperties()
                .setTitle("High-Performance Java Persistence")
                .setAuthor("Vlad Mihalcea")
                .setPublisher("Amazon")
                .setPrice(44.99D)
        )
);
```

When persisting the entity above, Hibernate generates the proper SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO book (
    isbn,
    properties,
    id
)
VALUES (
    '978-9730228236',
    '{  
        "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence",  
        "author": "Vlad Mihalcea",  
        "publisher": "Amazon",  
        "price": 44.99
    }',
    1
)
```

Changing the properties entity attribute is also much simpler when using a POJO:

```
Book book = entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .bySimpleNaturalId(Book.class)
    .load("978-9730228236");
 
book.getProperties().setUrl(
    "https://amzn.com/973022823X"
);
```

By updating the JSON entity attribute, Hibernate generates the proper SQL UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE
    book
SET
    properties = 
    '{  
        "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence",  
        "author": "Vlad Mihalcea",  
        "publisher": "Amazon",  
        "price": 44.99,  
        "url": "https://amzn.com/973022823X"
    }'
WHERE
    id = 1
```